# Alternatives to %matplotlib tk when using macOS- Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am trying to use %matplotlib tk on my macstudio

This is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib tk
plt.subplots(6,1, figsize=(40,10))
```

I am getting this error:

[image]
[image]

Any idea of how I could fic that? Is there another backened that might be comptible

Comment: I don't think you need an alternative. You need to provide parameters that make `height and width > 0`

Comment: I have tried with several options for figsize but it doesnt work with something. I think it's an issue of %matplotlib tk not being compatible with macos

Comment: The magic command is working as expected, as you can see in the traceback that invokes all the way to PIL library. You can reproduce outside of Jupyter with just importing pyplot... Pyplot works fine on my Mac